# Could not reconnect again to the same wifi network after disconnecting once in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

Hello everyone I am facing a problem with wifi, Once I disconnect a wifi network, I can't connect to it again without rebooting or unplugging and replugging the adapter. I am using
Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter

Driver is downloaded from https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

I did not have any issue with wifi in my previous distro which is MXLinux(Debian 11).

I tried to stop and restart the network but did not work.

Note: I have recently noticed, this happens only when the wifi strength is low and it disconnects. For example as I use mobile hotspot, when in connection I move my phone to some distance from the pc and I disconnect the wifi from mobile or it disconnects itself being out of range. In this case only I could not connect again to the same network even if I come closer to the pc. I need to unplug or re-plug the adapter or reboot the system. In my work I often come across such scenarios and it is frustrating. Earlier with MX Linux (debian 11) I did not have any issue like this. I changed my distro to Ubuntu because it has good support for my printer.

```
May 22 16:05:45 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751745.2736] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 22 16:05:45 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751745.2737] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 22 16:05:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751746.4640] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:05:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751746.4640] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751760.8713] device (wlx00e0202fda17): link timed out.
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.8713] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.8717] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751760.8720] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: failed for connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.8725] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.9022] dhcp4 (wlx00e0202fda17): canceled DHCP transaction
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.9023] dhcp4 (wlx00e0202fda17): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 22 16:06:00 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751760.9023] dhcp4 (wlx00e0202fda17): state changed no lease
May 22 16:06:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751763.6771] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 22 16:06:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751763.6771] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5660] policy: auto-activating connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5666] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: starting connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5667] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5669] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5671] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5673] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) access point 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, but secrets are required.
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5674] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5684] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5686] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5688] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5688] Config: added 'ssid' value 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5688] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5688] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5688] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5689] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5837] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:46 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751806.5838] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:47 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751807.8740] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:47 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751807.8740] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:49 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751809.7740] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:49 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751809.7741] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:51 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751811.5664] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:51 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751811.5665] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:53 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751813.4497] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:53 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751813.4497] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:06:59 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751819.2467] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:06:59 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751819.2468] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751823.1294] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751823.1294] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:11 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751831.8687] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
May 22 16:07:11 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751831.8688] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:11 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751831.8690] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 22 16:07:11 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751831.8693] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: failed for connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:07:11 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751831.8694] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3741] policy: auto-activating connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3747] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: starting connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3748] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3750] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3752] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3754] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) access point 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, but secrets are required.
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3754] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3765] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3767] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.3769] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.6664] Config: added 'ssid' value 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.6664] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.6664] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.6664] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
May 22 16:07:12 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751832.6664] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 22 16:07:15 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751835.4707] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:15 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751835.4708] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:17 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751837.3497] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:17 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751837.3497] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:28 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751848.1469] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:28 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751848.1469] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:30 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751850.0338] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:30 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751850.0339] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:37 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751857.8688] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
May 22 16:07:37 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751857.8688] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:37 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751857.8691] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 22 16:07:37 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751857.8693] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: failed for connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:07:37 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751857.8694] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3743] policy: auto-activating connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3748] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: starting connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' (accf82df-276f-4d0d-a86b-a8e62003d3dd)
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3749] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3751] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3753] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3756] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) access point 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, but secrets are required.
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3756] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3766] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3768] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.3771] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.6664] Config: added 'ssid' value 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.6664] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.6664] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.6664] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
May 22 16:07:38 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751858.6664] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 22 16:07:41 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751861.4707] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:41 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751861.4708] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:43 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751863.3491] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:43 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751863.3491] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:54 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751874.1467] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:54 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751874.1468] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 22 16:07:56 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751876.0219] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:07:56 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751876.0220] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 22 16:08:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751883.8688] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
May 22 16:08:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751883.8689] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:08:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751883.8692] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 22 16:08:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <warn>  [1684751883.8695] device (wlx00e0202fda17): Activation: failed for connection 'motorola edge 20 fusion_1741'
May 22 16:08:03 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751883.8698] device (wlx00e0202fda17): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 22 16:08:07 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751887.0253] device (wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May 22 16:08:07 A320M-S2H NetworkManager[736]: <info>  [1684751887.0254] device (p2p-dev-wlx00e0202fda17): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```